# TableView is not refreshing the first time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tableview

First of all, I'm sorry for my English, but I hope you'll understand what I wan't to ask ;)

I'm creating an Iphone-App . There is a Table-View with Subjects ( like Maths, English, etc.). When I select a row, a new TableView appears with my grades ( A, A+, etc.). In this TableView, I can add new tests. 
My problem is, when I created a test in a subject and I go back to the Subject-TableView and go again to the subject itself (So that I can see my individual tests), the TableView doesn't refresh every cel. So there are cells which aren't filled, until I add a new test. 
Do you have any idea what I can do? :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: As per your question it seems that you are not calling [tableView Reload] while going back.If this doesn't solves your issue.please share your code to help you out.

Comment: How are you persisting your whatever data you enter for the new test.

Answer (score 1):

rry to put  `[myTableView reloadData];` inside your `viewWillApear` as below:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: It's `-reloadData` not `-Reload`

Comment: @Mario Thanks body, typing mistake ;).

Answer (score 0):

in your `viewWillAppear`  do this

```
 [myTableView reloadData];
```